# How to add a node to the end of the textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have an array of control ids and this is how i retrieve them

```
var control = document.getElementById(arrVarIDToControlID[variable_id]);
```

for the text boxes am able to append the node to the parent node(textbox) but for the text area am not able to append the node to the parent(textarea) but it adds the node to the page instead

```
 control.parentNode.appendChild("text");
```

i use the above code to append. how can i be able to append to the textarea but not the page??

Comment: You tagged the question as related to jQuery but all I can see is native Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [insertAfter()](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) on the TextArea control.

```
$(arrVarIDToControlID[variable_id]).insertAfter("text");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
$('#'+arrVarIDToControlID[variable_id]).parent().append('<div>text</div>');
```

You can try to append the text only but I recommend to always use a container